# Maven install fails with my IntelliJ setting

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using this basic maven command :

`mvn install`

It stops, with the following error :

> [WARNING] File /home/vagrant/MyProject/application/declic2Parent/.idea/encodings.xml contains prohibited string.
>
> [...]
>
> [INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] Total time: 5.575s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 29 17:09:42 CEST 2018
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/737M
>
> [INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.rte.maven.plugin:encoding-maven-plugin:1.0.0.1:descriptor (executionEncoding) on project declic2Parent: We detect encoding errors on various files - see log! -> [Help 1]

What settings do I have to add in my pom.xml to tell him to stop looking in the IntelliJ directory ?

If I delete the file automatically created by IntelliJ the maven install succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to play with auto-generated files.

If you use characters like ñ, é, etc you may get this errors. 
It **may** get fixed if you add a  encoding.

Like this:

```
<configuration>
  <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
```